# Got error in asp.net c# while opening my project

Tags: asp.net

i just created a project in asp.net c# while transferring my project to my client i got stuck with this error" It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

how to overcome with this problem..please guide me...

Comment: As the message says, it seems that the directory where your application is located is not declared as a web application in IIS.
Declaring the directory as an application might do the trick (in IIS 7.5 web site : right-click the directory => "Convert to Application")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error when you have place a full web.config in a sub-directory and not on the root directory of your site.

So I say that you have copy your site on a sub-directory, and you need to move it to the root of your site.